# How do I delete CLI wallet?

Tags: solana-cli, cli

Folks! I imported the backpack wallet I created on CLI. I am trying to figure out how to delete it from my system (so that it's only in the backpack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though Solana wallets can exist anywhere in the file system depending on where they were created, most are located in `~/.config/solana` (on linux and mac systems).

That being said, please be sure that you have your recovery phrase or the private key data for the wallet securely stored somewhere in case you need to recover the wallet.